# Setting the Default Zoom of An Emacs Frame (Without Stutter)?

Tags: frames, fonts, zooming

When launching emacs, I've been manually calling

```
(dotimes (i (or arg 15))
    (spacemacs/zoom-frm-in))
```

to zoom the frame in 15 times over. I actually added this to a script so that it happens every time I launch a new instance of emacs.

The problem is that it is pretty laggy/takes a few seconds of stutter for it to achieve this.

**Question:** Is there a way to set the default size of an emacs frame when it launches (to avoid this stutter/lag) to 15x the default?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set the default for new frames by customizing option **`default-frame-alist`**: size, position, font size, whatever parameters you like. It's the font size that zooming changes.
2. Since you are using library [`zoom-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el), you can customize option `frame-zoom-font-difference`, to increase the size of a zoom increment. The doc of `zoom-frm-in` etc. tells you about this option.